# How to evaluate this integral in terms of a beta function?

Tags: integration, beta-function

I need some help evaluating an integral using beta function.

\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^4 \phi d\phi \cdot \frac{2\pi}{5}
\end{equation*}

I am not sure how to transform lower bound and cosine to fit the equation for beta function. I have to solve it using beta function because that's what the exercise says.

Comment: When you ask a question and [it is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021809/how-to-evaluate-integral-in-terms-of-a-beta-function), please do not repost it.  Instead, use the edit button to improve your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.

For any even (integrable) function $f$,
$$
\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=2\int_0^{a}f(x)dx
$$

Also, one of the [various ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas) to write the Beta function is:

$$
{\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\mathrm {B} (x,y)&=2\int _{0}^{\pi /2}(\sin \theta )^{2x-1}(\cos \theta )^{2y-1}\,d\theta \\[6pt]&
\end{aligned}}}
$$

Comment: thank you SO much for your help!

Comment: @luchka13: you are welcome!